# Can I get transit visa on arrival at Cochin airport?

Tags: visas, transit, india, check-in, indigo

Hy I am citizen of Bangladesh staying in Malaysia. I want to travel to Dubai from Kuala Lumpur  with different airlines. Air Asia to Cochin and Indigo to Dubai. I have 19 hours transit at Cochin airport, single ticket I mean booking number is the same on kiwi.com with no check in baggage.

I wrote to Indigo about the check in process. They replied that I have to cross the immigration check at Cochin airport to get my boarding pass.
My question is Do I need a transit visa for Cochin airport.
How can I get a transit visa? On arrival or in advance?

Answer (score 5):

Cochin airport does not currently have an airside transit facility; everyone who arrives from outside India must clear immigration and customs before going to their next flight. This means that you will require a visa to enter India.

You can obtain a transit visa which allows you to enter India for up to 3 days. You will be able to leave the airport with this visa. There is not a visa on arrival; you must obtain the visa in advance. You can obtain the visa by following the [instructions given at the High Commission of India in Kuala Lumpur](https://hcikl.gov.in/pages?id=eyJpdiI6IlVZdW9TNGd0blRFcmVIbzl0TExmM2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZTJXMW4yaTdZRmlGcXEybHd4eER0Zz09IiwibWFjIjoiMWFlMjg1ODYzMjAwNDY4ZDk4MmYxYjBjN2E4ZmU1YzMyY2ViM2NlOWIxNDY0ZWM3YmQxMTc2NzliMjQ5NGViMyJ9&subid=eyJpdiI6Ill2aUo2TGxxSWdGRnhocnZobzFVcHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoib1djcHZcL3EzNE1KK2d5eWxaOVA1dEE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjE0MDEwMWM4MTVjYjU4ZmZjOWU2YzY2MzQzZWIxZTY3MjhiNWIzN2JkZWNjYjgzZmVlYTkzYzZmMzc2YTRkYjAifQ==). There are many fake web sites and service providers; you should use only those web sites and service providers given by the High Commission.